# Polymer 1.1 binding to array values

Tags: polymer, polymer-1.0

I have a form like this

```
       <div class="warranty-part">
        <paper-input maxlength="4" name="warranty[0]" no-label-float label="1111" value="{{warranty0::input}}"></paper-input>
      </div>
      <div class="warranty-part">
        <paper-input maxlength="4" name="warranty[1]" no-label-float label="1111" value="{{warranty1::input}}"></paper-input>
      </div>
      <div class="warranty-part">
        <paper-input maxlength="4" name="warranty[2]" no-label-float label="1111" value="{{warranty2::input}}"></paper-input>
      </div>
      <div class="warranty-part">
        <paper-input maxlength="4" name="warranty[3]" no-label-float label="1111" value="{{warranty3::input}}"></paper-input>
      </div>
```

With four different fields. Each of these input values is bound to one property defined like...

```
   properties: {

    warranty0: {
      type: String,
      observer: 'onWarrantyChange0'
    },

     warranty1: {
      type: String,
      observer: 'onWarrantyChange1'
    },

     warranty2: {
      type: String,
      observer: 'onWarrantyChange2'
    },

     warranty3: {
      type: String,
      observer: 'onWarrantyChange3'
    }
  }
```

This works... but what would be tidier is to be able to bind to array values for each of the fields to tidy things up.

Like

```
properties: {

    warranty: {
      type: Array,
      value: ['','','',''],
      observer: 'onWarrantyChange'
    }
  }
```

But I just can't work out how to bind to an index of an array with polymer. From reading the docs I got the impression that binding to the input value like this would work...

```
    value="{{warranty.0::input}}"
```

But it doesn't.

Is there any way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try `{{warranty.0}}`, `{{warranty.1}}`, etc..

But if you update any of the `paper-input`'s `value`, the `onWarrantyChange` observer won't be called as you will need a special `*` syntax for property change notification inside an array (See [this](https://www.polymer-project.org/1.0/docs/devguide/properties.html#array-observation)).

```
properties: {
  warranty: {
    type: Array,
    value: ['111','222','333','444']
  }
},

observers: ['onWarrantyChange(warranty.*)'],

onWarrantyChange: function (changedWarranty) {
  console.log(changedWarranty);
}
```

See this [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/mvLN58WIKMyhVgkqm1dC?p=preview) for reference.

---

### Update

Looks like the Polymer could be confused by bindings of *valued type* string literals. So a simple workaround would be to define an array with 4 objects like this -

```
value: [ { value: '' }, { value: '' }, { value: '' }, { value: '' } ]
```

And the bindings will become -

`value="{{warranty.0.value}}"`, `value="{{warranty.1.value}}"`, etc..

See this new [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/vukikHoarenhPqITRUDD?p=preview).

Comment: Thanks very much for your answer!! That's a great way to approach it. Only thing I've found is when you start the array values off as empty strings all values bind to the last array value.. eg http://plnkr.co/edit/y5nGZGHnSjvnKVz4TWPK?p=preview

Comment: Because those string literals are **equal** to each other and this confuses Polymer which always picks the last one to update (see this line `var key = coll.getKey(old);` in Polymer.html). So maybe change the `value` to `[new String(), new String(), new String(), new String()]`. However, doing this will make the `paper-input` lose the default `label` display. In your particular case, since you have `no-label-float`, a quick solution might be to simply use `placeholder` instead of `label` as they have the exact look and feel. See [this](http://plnkr.co/edit/TXfwan8WcxP2ybCxQQNv?p=preview).

Comment: Actually, a better approach might be to define the array with 4 *objects* so they are reference typed. See my updated answer.